# Consuming time based file paths in flink based on current time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a list of time stamped S3 objects

eg: s3://01-02-20:10:00:00 , s3://01-02-20:10:00:01

and so on.

I want to consume all files which are within the last 5 minutes from S3 into flink as a DataSource and have checkpointing work as expected.

Can we do this with current File based source / Is this even possible ?

Comment: Create your own data source `RichSourceFunction` and filter the events in the `run` method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no source function available for your requirement, you need to implement a RichSourceFunction yourself and filter out the file path you need

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.